# Is it possible to perform parallel nested transactions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've a scenario were I need to call a set of different Oracle procedures in parallel. These procedures must share the same initial context which has uncommitted transactions. I cannot commit the parent transaction under the danger of having read inconsistency between those parallel processes.

Is it possible in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

One thing comes to my mind: mapreduce with table functions http://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/mapreduce_oracle_tablefunction

I've used this in several scenarios to run things concurrently, though I'm not sure it is applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this using the [DBMS_XA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xa.htm) package, which allows you to "switch or share transactions across SQL*Plus sessions or processes using PL/SQL".

[Oracle-Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_xa_11gR1.php) has a good example of how to use the package.

(But if your goal is to use parallelism to improve performance you should use normal statement-level parallel execution instead.)

Answer (score -1):

Far as I know: no.

`DBMS_JOB` and `DBMS_SCHEDULER` can be used to run Oracle procedures in parallel but they run them in their own sessions.